# How do I get the last and second last values in a row for another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently trying to use Sheet1! in these two functions, but it just keeps giving me errors. Any tips?

```
=INDEX(1:1,LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1<>""),COLUMN(1:1))) 
=INDEX(1:1,LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1<>""),COLUMN(1:1))-1)
```

Comment: what about `=INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!1:1<>""),COLUMN(1:1))) `

Comment: Or `=LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!1:1<>""),Sheet1!1:1)`

Answer (score 0):

**Last Value:** `=INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(Sheet1!1:1<>"")*COLUMN(1:1),1))`
                                                                                                                                    ^
**Penultimate:** `=INDEX(Sheet1!1:1,AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(Sheet1!1:1<>"")*COLUMN(1:1),2))`
                                                                                                                                       ^